# What will be the effect of $(q \circ f_k)$ on the homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f_k : S^n \longrightarrow S^n$ be a map of degree $k.$ Consider $q \circ f_k : S^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R P^n.$ Compute the homology $H_*(\text {Cone} (q \circ f_k))\ $?

Let $X = \text {Cone} (q \circ f_k).$ I know that we can able to find a long exact sequence of the homology groups $$\cdots \longrightarrow H_m (S^n) \longrightarrow H_m (\mathbb R P^n) \longrightarrow H_m (X) \longrightarrow H_{m-1} (S^n) \longrightarrow H_{m-1} (\mathbb R P^n) \longrightarrow \cdots$$

If we can somehow able to figure out what is $(q \circ f_k)_* : H_* (S^n) \longrightarrow H_* (\mathbb R P^n)$ then we are through. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well $f_k$ is multiplication by $k$ so we only need to check what $q$ is because of functoriality of $H_*$

Comment: @Noel Lundström $q : S^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R P^n$ is the two sheeted covering map and hence it induces multiplication by $2$ on the homology groups. Hence $q \circ f_k$ induces multiplication by $2k$ on the homology groups. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the sum of local degrees theorem would imply that if $n$ is odd (i.e $\mathbb R P ^n$ is orientable) then $q_*$ is multiplication by $2$ if the orientation of $\mathbb RP^n$ is induced from the one on $S^n$. If $n$ is even then $q_*$ is obviously zero since the top homology of $\mathbb RP^n$ would be zero.